# Saving a Bootstrap Carousel to PDF

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I've been working on this for a few days and getting nowhere...

We have a paper book that we are trying to digitise and add interactivity to (the book has some fields that can be filled out, etc.). The idea was that we would put each page as one slide in a Bootstrap carousel, and then let the user switch between the pages and fill out the text boxes. So far so good, that part is mostly working fine.

Now we need to also be able to export or save the filled out pages to a PDF. I've tried many things with jsPDF and html2canvas, and none of it seems to be behaving correctly. I am relatively novice at programming in Javascript. I have two issues:

1) If I only convert one slide of the carousel at a time, then the output PDF looks awful. Really really low quality with lots of artifacts. I can't figure out how to make the output faithful to what is shown to the user on the screen.

Code for converting one slide to PDF:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('pg'+i), {
  onrendered: function(canvasObj) {
    var pdf = new jsPDF();
    var image = canvasObj.toDataURL("image/png");

    pdf.addImage(image, "png", 0, 0, 210, 297);
  }
});
```

2) If I try to convert multiple slides of the carousel into a multi-page PDF, I get lots of errors about not being able to read the slides. I suspect that it is only able to read the slide and the contents of the slide if they are currently active and visible on the screen.

Code for converting multiple slides to a single multi-page PDF:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF();
for (var i=1;i<=16;i++) {
  $('#bookCarousel').carousel(i);
  html2canvas(document.getElementById('pg'+i), {
    onrendered: function(canvasObj) {
        var image = canvasObj.toDataURL("image/png");

        pdf.addImage(image, "png", 0, 0, 210, 297);
        if (i < 16) {pdf.addPage();}
        console.log(i);
    }
  });
}
pdf.save('booklet.pdf');
```

Any suggestions for how to fix this or obvious signs of doing something wrong? (Or an alternative, better way of achieving this goal?)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps anyone else, it turns out that the correct answer to 2) is not to use Promises, but rather to listen to the 'slid.bs.carousel' event generated by the Bootstrap carousel so that you know when the slide has completed.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');

var pagenum = 1;
$('#bookCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () { //After each slide
    var pg = document.getElementById("pg"+pagenum.toString());
    //Set up the canvas on the page/div
    html2canvas(pg, {width:pg.scrollWidth, height:pg.scrollHeight, logging:false})
            .then(function(canvas){
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
                pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0);

                //Assuming there are 16 pages in total
                if (pagenum<16) {
                    pdf.addPage()
                    pagenum++;
                    slideCarousel(pagenum); //Slide to the next page
                } else {
                    //Save the book, turn off the event listener
                    pdf.save("booklet.pdf")
                    $('#bookCarousel').off('slid.bs.carousel');
                };
            });
});
slideCarousel(pagenum); //Start it all off
```

1) is somewhat fixed by running this function without Inspect Element open, so that the image size is actually closer to the correct size and less downsampling happens.